# Existence of basis of $P_2$ with no polynomial of degree 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question: Is there a basis for the vector space of polynomials of degree 2 or less consisting of three polynomial vectors $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$, where none is a polynomial of degree 1?

We know that the standard basis for the vector space is $\{1,t,t^2\}$. However, this wouldn't be allowed because there is a polynomial of degree 1 in this basis.

Comment: $t^2 , t^2+t , t^2+1$ Is such a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, $\;\{\;1,\,x^2+1,\,x^2+x\;\}\;$ . Check that

$$0=a+b(x^2+1)+c(x^2+x)=(b+c)x^2+cx+a+b\iff a=b=c=0$$